# Call Batch from REST Resource

Tags: rest-api, apexrest

I have created the Rest Resource to send the data with Attachment to outside the salesforce (GET Method - REST API).

```
@HttpGet 
global static List<wrapper1> getCVH() { 
wrapper1.rows row; 
for(CVH__c cvh: database.query(queryString)){ 
    List <Attachment> attachmentList = [SELECT Id, Name, Body, ParentId FROM 
    Attachment WHERE ParentId = :cvh.Id limit 1]; 
    if (attachmentList.size() > 0){ 
      Attachment att = attachmentList[0]; row.AttachmentName = att.Name; 
    row.AttachmentBody = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(att.Body); //This line is causing error 
} 
} 
lstConv.add(cvhWrap); 
return lstConv; 
}
```

The problem is I am getting the error

> System.LimitException: JSON string exceeds heap size limit

Now, I now that for synchronous call the heap size limit is 6 MB and I can increase it to 12 MB if I do asynchronous call(Batch or Future).

But I didn't have an idea how can I achieve that.

Please let me know how can I achieve this?

Here is a code snippet:

```
@HttpGet global static List<wrapper1> getCVH() { 
    wrapper1.rows row; 
    for(CVH__c cvh: database.query(queryString)){ 
        List <Attachment> attachmentList = [SELECT Id, Name, Body, ParentId FROM Attachment WHERE ParentId = :cvh.Id limit 1]; 
        if (attachmentList.size() > 0){ 
            Attachment att = attachmentList[0]; 
            row.AttachmentName = att.Name; 
            row.AttachmentBody = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(att.Body); //This line is causing error 
        } 
    } 

    lstConv.add(cvhWrap); 
    return lstConv; 
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide at least the method signature and preferably the line that is causing the issue?

Comment: @HttpGet
global static List<wrapper1> getCVH() {
    wrapper1.rows row;
    for(CVH__c cvh: database.query(queryString)){
        List <Attachment> attachmentList = [SELECT Id, Name, Body, ParentId FROM Attachment WHERE ParentId = :cvh.Id limit 1];  
  if (attachmentList.size() > 0){
            Attachment att = attachmentList[0];
            row.AttachmentName = att.Name;
            row.AttachmentBody = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(att.Body); //This line is causing error
        }
    }
    lstConv.add(cvhWrap);
    return lstConv;
}